# Is it possible to avoid pulling before pushing?

Tags: git

I must say I'm sort of new to Git and there's loads of things about it that I still don't clearly understand. However, the one that concerns me most at the time being is the **pull before you push** issue.

I'm working on a project and want to commit changes to the remote server (not GitHub). So let's say I made some changes to the project locally, and now want to send the corrected files to the remote repository with some old version of my project stored there. Git would want me to pull (fetch + merge) the files from the remote server, but obviously I don't need them, as pulling them would simply destroy all the changes I made on my local machine.

How would I push changes to the remote server avoiding, if possible, pulling the previous version (in my case the very first commit)? If it's not possible then what are the most reasonable workarounds here?

Comment: Your question seems to be based on the misconception that Git will "destroy all the changes I made on my local machine". This is not the case. Git tries very hard to *not* destroy uncommitted work.

Answer (score 1):

Well you need to acknowledge the changes made by other user at least. Nothing stops you from overwriting everything your way. You can fetch the commits and then just merge it the way you want it.

But I think the best way for you is working on different branch maybe.

Answer (score 1):

In short:  what you are attempting to do will cause **more harm, pain and misunderstanding** than is necessary in this scenario.  While you most certainly can force-push your commits, ***do not do this*** unless you are ***certain*** that you are not stepping on anyone else's toes while doing so.

---

Git will not actively destroy your changes.  In fact, if it finds something that it alone cannot handle, it will alert you (in the form of a merge conflict) about something that it can't resolve.

That aside, the misconception about you not needing the remote changes is incorrect.  If someone else pushes to the remote repository, then the expectation is that whatever code you've written shouldn't conflict with theirs.

Merge conflicts aren't fun to deal with, but if you find yourself running into them often, there are some things you can do to mitigate them:

- Base your work off of the most recent copy of whatever main development branch you're working off of.  If you can, rebase your branch against that too to ensure that you're not several commits behind.
- Touch a handful of files in a very narrow scope at a time.  If you find yourself touching a lot of files at once, be sure to communicate that you're doing this; someone may have a way to avoid this scenario.
- **If all else fails**, talk to the other developer that pushed code to see what the conflict was, why it happened, and how it needs to be resolved.  Here, **communication** is key; if you don't talk with the other developer, then conflicts can be very painful if you don't understand why code is where it is now.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is

1. Create a local branch.
2. Once you create/checkout this new branch, you can work **independently** from your production code
3. After you've made your desired updates to your new branch you would simply push to your remote-branch. (now your branch is up to date with your changes)
4. Pull it into production

Git documentation is great. It trumps my explanation [Git Documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control)

Comment: Well that was the first thing that came to my mind actually, I just wasn't altogether sure that it's reasonable enough...so to speak. Aye, the documentation is just grand. Ta!

Answer (score 0):

In short: Yes, it is possible. However, I am not sure if you really want to avoid pulling.

What pulling does is basically synchronizing the remote server with your local repository. If there are any new commits (aka changes) you do not have in your local repository, git will try to apply and merge them. If there are no new commits, you can simply push.

Now if there are other commits and you really don't care about them, you can use push with the force option. This will override the remote with your local changes. However, this is a bad practice if you are not the only one working with that repository (and it might be even prohibited) and you should really know what you are doing. Force pushing can lead to lost commits.

Comment: well as regards this particular project, it's entirely mine and I'm the only one working on it, so from what you've said, I gather it would be safe to push changes the hard way, so to speak. But indeed if I were not the only one commiting, it would be a bad practice. I got it. Many thanks.